# How to persist child entity referencing already persisted parent entity

Tags: hibernate

I have a Parent & Child entities. 
Parent is mapped to Child with @OneToMany
Child is mapped with Parent as @ManyToOne.

I would like to first insert Parent, then perform action and create list of childs and insert them.
I am looking if there is a way to make it happen. So that i will try to apply Batch inserts to Childs since i am mixing the child persist with Parent.
I would like to gain the performance of having each database call for each child insert, but rather single db call for all childs.

If there is a way to achieve please help. 
I tried with few options but they failed complaining "cannot insert the value NULL into column , table CHILD; Column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Please throw some pointers to overcome this situation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TABLE_NAME)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", length = 1, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
@AttributeOverride(name = UniqueIdentifierEntity.ID_NAME, column = @Column(name = ColumnName, length = 36))
public class Parent extends UniqueIdentifierEntity{

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)    
private final Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<Child>();
//getter of childs
//Setter of childs
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {Child.CHILD_ID_COLUMN }))
@AttributeOverride(name = UniqueIdentifierEntity.ID_NAME, column = @Column(name = Child.CHILD_ID_COLUMN, length = 36))
@BatchSize(size = 10)
public  class Child extends UniqueIdentifierEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    private Parent parent;

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the model classes as well as method of class which is persisting the data in database

Comment: updated the question with entities. Please ignore the formatting issues. Please let me know if there is a way to overcome the situation